# Font Awesome Unicode Some are working some are not?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Trying to get some font awesome icons infront of my list item.

Ive got an arrow which is not working while its a free version 5 icon.
Try to add another icon which is also free version 5.0.9 and this is working?

In my FA account im just using version 5 what do I wrong?

Someone who can help me?

Working

```
li::before {
   font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free'
   content: '\f2b5'
}
```

Not working

```
li::before {
   font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free'
   content: '\f061'
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653474/fontawesome-unicodes-dont-seem-to-work) might help.

Comment: Not the same problem, he just forgot to add font-family

Comment: What happens if you install this font on your computer and try entering the same characters? If both appear, that tells you the font definitely contains both characters, so the problem is in your code. If the same character doesn't appear, that tells you the problem's with the font.

Comment: Find out that the problem is font-family: 'FontAwesome' instead of font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free'

Comment: no, it's not the font-family. This will make you fallback to the V4. You need to adjust the font-weight